# Unsigned integer nibbles treated as binary compressed to unsigned integer

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have come up with the following to represent a binary using an unsigned integer. For ex: `0x1111` is stored as `0xf(15)`.
I am aware that there are already solutions like `BOOST_BINARY`, `C++14` binary literals and macro tricks to represent a binary number.
I just wanted to get this working with templates( inspired by the factorial example).
The following solution is more than enough for my task at hand.

Any idea on how to extend this to more than `uint64_t` with templates and not macros (also no `C++14` yet only `C++11`) or on how to improve this/loop holes? I am just curious.
Thanks

```
template <>
struct Uint64Nibbles2Binary<0x0>
{
  enum {value = 0x0};
};

template <uint64_t num>
struct Uint64Nibbles2Binary
{
  enum 
  {
    value = (Uint64Nibbles2Binary<(num >> 4)>::value << 0x1) | (num & 0x1);
  };
};
```

Comment: Well, if nothing else you can squeeze in more digits in octal than hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++14, just use `0b1111`.  And done.  They have built-in binary literal support.

In C++11 you'll want to use `operator""`.

```
constexpr int64_t make_binary() { return 0; }

template<class...Rest>
constexpr int64_t make_binary( char C, Rest...rest ) {
  return ((C=='1') << sizeof...(Rest)) + make_binary(rest...);
}

template <char...Cs>
constexpr int64_t operator"" _binary() {
  static_assert(sizeof...(Cs) <= 64, "Binary value has too many bits");
  return make_binary(Cs...);
}
```

then:

```
111011110101101_binary
```

is a binary literal calculated at compile time.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/665560dbc96c8109)

The size of the binary output is limited by a 64 bit int.  The input, naturally, is limited to 64 bits.  Use no prefix.  Error checking to eliminate non-`0` and non-`1` values at compile time is possible.